# Blog publishing / creation from Latex

Tags: sweave, knitr, eclipse, rstudio

I have been using Latex for a few years, and have several articles written in Latex. I want to share some of these articles on blogs, and I am very new to the blogging world.

Just wondering if there are any blogs which support a latex file/folder upload?
If not, may be a way to get an output and upload it to the blog with hyperlinks etc?

Ideal would be a package that can publish directly from my Eclipse / RStudio UI to the blog, or even a command line tool would be just awesome.

Many thanks.

Comment: Do you want to post PDFs to a blog? Or source code?

Comment: I dont want to post PDFs or the source code. But the final output which hopefully is in HTML format with plots / images.

Comment: So you want to convert complete LaTeX documents to HTML pages? Have you looked at `tex4ht`?